# Issues when resizing the bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I've been using bootstrap for one of the first times and I'm having issues resizing the carousel on one of my pages with a gradient background in the body and an overlay bg in the content section.

So in the first link I have implement the same code but when I resize vertically smaller the container doesn't overlap the content.

How can I get the second link to be like this and I still want it to resize properly for different resolutions. I just want the container to be in a fixed position below the content.

http://thehedonistproject.com/launch/index.html

http://thehedonistproject.com/launch/trader-dans.html

```
<section class="slider" id="slider">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="myCarousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->


        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>


            <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>


            <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>


            <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>


            <li data-slide-to="4" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>


            <li data-slide-to="5" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>


            <li data-slide-to="6" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>


            <li data-slide-to="7" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>


            <li data-slide-to="8" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>


            <li data-slide-to="9" data-target="#myCarousel">
            </li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->


        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo1.jpg">
            </div>


            <div class="item"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo4.jpg">
            </div>


            <div class="item"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo3.jpg">
            </div>


            <div class="item"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo2.jpg">
            </div>


            <div class="item"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo5.jpg">
            </div>


            <div class="item"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo6.jpg">
            </div>


            <div class="item"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo7.jpg">
            </div>


            <div class="item"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo8.jpg">
            </div>


            <div class="item"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo9.jpg">
            </div>


            <div class="item"><img alt="" src="img/photos/trader-dans/photo10.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
         <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" role="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: try  `#slider{ clear: both; }` , It might give you desire output.

Answer (score 0):

I advise that for effective editing of bootstrap carousel, link the stylesheet in the docs example folder `bootstrap\docs\example\carousel` to your html and edit that stylesheet. Since you want to resize vertically, change the heights of these three in the `carousel.css`

```
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Hey when I implement that code, I still have the exact same issue, when making the browser vertically smaller, just on the page with the background gradient. the img stays in place but the container doesn't resize and moves upwards.

Comment: Your links are not opening. Need to see to really understand what you talking about.